# How to reformat "d-m-Y - d-m-Y" string to "Y-m-d Y-m-d"?

Tags: php, date, format, date-range, date-parsing

I want to change the format of a string containing two `d-m-Y` date strings separated by space hyphen space (representing a range).  The desired output should have a format of `Y-m-d - Y-m-d`.

I can successfully execute a similar technique with `d/m/Y - d/m/Y` strings, but something isn't right when I am parsing the format of these new strings.

My code:

```
$date = "25-05-2020 - 30-05-2020";

$string = explode('-', $date);
$date1 = explode('-', $string[0]);
$date2 = explode('-', $string[1]);

$date1 = $date1[2] . '-' . $date1[0] . '-' . $date1[1];
$date2 = $date2[2] . '-' . $date2[0] . '-' . $date2[1];

echo $date1 . ' - ' . $date2;
```

My desired output from the sample input is `2020-05-25 - 2020-05-30`.

Comment: Add spaces before and after - to your first explode function:   $string = explode(' - ',$date);

Comment: could you please elaborate the code... I could not understand

Comment: If you want to split your two dates you need to use a space before and after "-" in your first explode function. Otherwise you split it by every "-" in the string not just the one in the middle. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a space before and after `-` like below:

```
<?php

$date = "25-05-2020 - 30-05-2020";
$splitted_dates = explode(" - ",$date);
$date1 = $splitted_dates[0];
$date2 = $splitted_dates[1];

echo $date1, " " , $date2;
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/QTIHd

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
<?php
$date = "25-05-2020 - 30-05-2020";

preg_match_all('/\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}/', $date, $matches);

list ($date1, $date2) = $matches[0];

echo $date1." ".$date2;
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e1224cc164155e1231131985e74dc7ed531393cb)

Answer (score 0):

I find the most direct technique to be a single `preg_replace()` call that swaps the day and year values for each date in the string.  In doing so, there is no need to generate any temporary arrays to convert the input string into the output string.

- capture: day number (`$1`)
- capture: hyphen, month number, hyphen (`$2`)
- capture: year number (`$3`)
- match: space, hyphen, space
- capture: day number (`$4`)
- capture: hyphen, month number, hyphen (`$5`)
- capture: year number (`$6`)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iVB6X))

```
var_export(
    preg_replace(
        '~(\d{2})(-\d{2}-)(\d{4}) - (\d{2})(-\d{2}-)(\d{4})~',
        '$3$2$1 - $6$5$4',
        '25-05-2020 - 30-05-2020'
    )
);
```

Output:

```
'2020-05-25 - 2020-05-30'
```